# Can you make Gmail show plain text only messages in fixed-width font?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to make Gmail display messages with only `text/plain` content using a constant width font? To clarify, I'd still prefer `multipart/alternative` messages with an HTML part to be shown in HTML mode. (In other words, **just like Thunderbird** does it.)

I receive some plain text messages with table-like formatting, which obviously depends on constant-width font. Gmail breaks the formatting like this:

[image]

I would want something like this, of course:

[image]

(Showing messages matching a certain filter (or tagged with certain label) in fixed width would be an equally good solution here, so if that's possible, please let me know!)

I looked around Gmail settings, but couldn't easily find anything related. The "**Show original**" option is a work-around, but it's rather clumsy if you always have to do that.

---

This is a repost of an old (unresolved) [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/29371/how-to-make-gmail-show-certain-plain-text-messages-in-constant-width-font/29383) ([Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:JOUpBZ-0evgJ:superuser.com/questions/29371/how-to-make-gmail-show-certain-plain-text-messages-in-constant-width-font/29383&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a)). I would have rather *migrated* it to Webapps, but that's not possible as it seems  delete-happy SU moderators have recently removed it altogether for some reason.

Comment: I'd say this is still unresolved.  I can change how I see text/plain email, but I want gmail to render it that way for the recipinets so I can send nicely formatted plain text tables, etc.  Until Google steps up, this will remain unresolved.  How to we get /them/ for fix this?

Answer (score 15):

Update 2019-07-15:

The `gmail-fixed-font` extension is now hosted on github: https://github.com/jparise/gmail-fixed-font

The instructions are provided in the repo README, but to summarise (assuming you are using Chrome):

1. Download the script
2. Open a new tab and navigate to `chrome://extensions/`
3. Enable Developer Mode
4. Drag and drop the script onto the window and install
5. (optional) you may want to allow the extension only for the gmail domain by clicking Details > Site Access: On specific sites and enter `https://mail.google.com` in the dialogue box and save

---

Ok, you have to try [Gmail Fixed Font](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/17869) userscript

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Gmail Fixed Font
// @namespace      http://www.indelible.org/
// @description    Fixed-font message bodies for Gmail
// @author         Jon Parise, James Tunnicliffe
// @version        1.3
// @include        http://mail.google.com/*
// @include        https://mail.google.com/*
// @include        http://*.mail.google.com/*
// @include        https://*.mail.google.com/*
// @grant          GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

// Plain-text Message Body
var css = ".ii, .Ak { font: medium monospace !important; }";
// Compose Interface
css += ".editable { font: medium monospace !important; }";

if (typeof GM_addStyle != "undefined") {
    GM_addStyle(css);
} else if (typeof addStyle != "undefined") {
    addStyle(css);
} else {
    var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
    if (heads.length > 0) {
        var node = document.createElement("style");
        node.type = "text/css";
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        heads[0].appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great in Chrome 79 with TamperMonkey. Please consider submitting it to GreasyFork.org.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Chrome, the [Gmail Fixed Width Text](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gamfbnidfgeeahogblblgafgpdhdkmib) extension takes care of it.

Comment: +1, good to know, even if this doesn't do exactly what I want (it uses fixed width also for multipart messages that do contain a HTML part)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the new Gmail compose.

Answer (score 5):

Next you can choose "Reply" or "Forward" and change Font to Courier New.

Comment: Frankly, this seems clumsy. Even the "show original" workaround (mentioned in the question) is handier, and what I'm looking for is something automatic...

Answer (score 4):

This was driving me nuts but I only wanted monospace for certain mailing lists and wanted to be able to adjust font-size too.

After looking at the existing solutions and suggestions I ended up creating a new Chrome Extension (free & open source) that applies CSS properties by GMail label. I already had GMail rules to apply labels to my mailing list messages so this worked well for me.

The CSS selectors & logic should be more reliable than the `.ii, .Ak` mentioned in other answers. You can apply different style properties for the message view and the reply/forward editor.

You can use the published version in the Chrome Web Store or install from source in developer mode.

Source: https://github.com/mscalora/GMailStyleByLabel

Chrome Web Store: [GMail Label Styler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmaillabelstyler/bdabigdipmikljbdbmglcjlhpnoagfjb)

Comment: If only this applied to the editor when replying

Answer (score 3):

If you use any custom CSS extension, such as Stylish or my favorite, Stylebot, you can just paste the CSS used by the userscript above:

```
.ii, .Ak  { font: medium monospace !important; }
.editable { font: medium monospace !important; }
```

Still working as of 2017

Comment: Doesn't seem to be *quite* enough in 2019 ...

Comment: As of July 2021 I use `.a3s {font: medium monospace !important;}` to change the font of the body text.

Comment: Here is that as a bookmarklet:

javascript:var style = document.createElement('style');style.innerHTML='.a3s {font: medium monospace !important;}';document.head.appendChild(style);